# Generic type works with function argument for map but not single value

Tags: typescript

```
interface DataGeneric {
    value: number;
}

function transform<D extends DataGeneric>(data: DataGeneric[], get_value: (record: D) => number) {

    // Works without error
    let values = data.map(get_value);
    // Following line errors with:
    //    Argument of type 'DataGeneric' is not assignable to parameter of type 'D'.
    //
    values = data.map(d => get_value(d));
    // Works without error, but why us type assertion needed?
    values = data.map(d => get_value(d as D));
}
```

I'm wondering why the type assertion is needed when passing a single value to `get_value`?

Typescript 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you need to cast to `D` or get the error:

> Argument of type 'DataGeneric' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'D'

Is this:

```
interface DataGeneric2 extends DataGeneric {
    value2: string;
}

transform([{ value: 3 }], (record: DataGeneric2) => {
    return record.value2.length;
});
```

In this example, the function that is being passed as `get_value` expects to get values of type `DataGeneric2` and not `DataGeneric`.
That is the error that the compiler is complaining about that:
Argument of type 'DataGeneric' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DataGeneric2'.

When you cast it to `D` (or change the signature of the function) then you tell the compiler that you know what you're doing and that it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the type assertion by changing the function signature to:

```
function transform<D extends DataGeneric>(data: D[], get_value: (record: D) => number) {
```

Comment: is that what you were asking? because you did not explain why the type assertion is needed in your original code

Comment: @NitzanTomer it's not really what I was asking... I've found a solution which I've posted as an answer but I don't fully understand why you have to define data as `D[]` or why you need `d as D` as shown in the question.  Regarding "you did not explain why the type assertion is needed", if you do not use the type assertion of `d as D` then you get the error: "Argument of type 'DataGeneric' is not assignable to parameter of type 'D'." despite `D extends DataGeneric`.